# How to delete a Copay wallet

Tags: copay

How to delete a Copay wallet when there is nothing showing on my device to do so. I clicked the plus (+) sign next to Bitcoinc on the home page and got many ways to create wallets, but no way to delete a wallet.

Comment: What OS are you running? Do you want to delete a wallet file, or the copay wallet app itself?

Answer (score 1):

- open the wallet which youd like to delete so that you see the balance and transactions
- click the settings icon in the top right corner
  [image: Settings]
- scroll down to the bottom
- last config option is called „delete wallet“